# Why is safari browser displaying cancel instead of ok button in javascript alert box?

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

I'm using a javascript alert box. It's displaying fine in other browsers. But in Safari browser, it's displaying Cancel button instead of OK button.

How to display an OK button in javascript alert box in Safari browser?

```
function displayPopup(cb) {
  alert('That is Great.');
}
```

We are calling this function here:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkmodeOnline" name="chkMode" runat="server" value="1" clientidmode="Static" onclick='displayPopup(this);' />
```

Comment: Weird, Safari 10 doesn't have *OK* or *Cancel*, it has *Close*. The *alert* dialog is a host object that is implementation dependent, so you get what you get.

Comment: Thanks RobG. But is there some option to get OK button instead of Close in safari?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: @Anshul—no. If script could modify the button names on alerts, prompts, etc. imagine the (malicious) fun you could have… ;-) Though you can construct identical UI objects that do whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @RobG